# how to mock hard private property in class in unit test in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing

I have a class with hard private property, how to I mock the value in unit test so I should have something like  `expect(event.getEventHis()).toBeEqual(['a', 'b'])`

```
export class EventController {
  #event: [];
  constructor() {
    this.#event = [];
    this.#lastIndex = 0;
  }

  getEventHis(): [] {
    return this.#event;
  }

  getLastIndex(): number {
    return this.#lstastIndex;
  }

}
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to mock the `getEventHis()` method and its returned value.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
export class EventController {
  #event: string[];
  #lastIndex: number;

  constructor() {
    this.#event = [];
    this.#lastIndex = 0;
  }

  getEventHis(): string[] {
    return this.#event;
  }

  getLastIndex(): number {
    return this.#lastIndex;
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { EventController } from './';

describe('68199289', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    jest.spyOn(EventController.prototype, 'getEventHis').mockReturnValueOnce(['a', 'b']);
    const event = new EventController();
    expect(event.getEventHis()).toEqual(['a', 'b']);
  });
});
```